# tapping on displayed button triggers hidden button event in background

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two buttons at the same location (one over the other, absolute position). I am using Jquery mobile 1.4 and Phonegap 3.3.

button#1 is initially `visible`

button#2 is initially `hidden`

When I tap on button#1, it should hide button#1 and display button#2.

But the weird thing is that, when tapping on button#1, it also triggers on button#2, like if it were already displayed. So with the code below, tapping on button#1, hides button#1, displays button#2, hides buttons#2 and displays button#1...back to where we started !

Is there something I am doing wrong ?

HTML:

```
      <a id="miniWeightLevel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all">My Factor</a>
            <div id="minifyCross">
                <div id="minifybutton" class="ui-btn btn-small-round ui-icon-delete ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline"></div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#welcome-page', function(event, docdata){     
    //initial state : 
    $('#miniWeightLevel').hide();
    $('#minifyCross').show();

    //bindings :
    $('#miniWeightLevel').unbind('vclick').bind('vclick', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#miniWeightLevel').hide();
        $('#minifyCross').show();
    });
    $('#minifyCross').unbind('vclick').bind('vclick', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('#miniWeightLevel').show();
        $('#minifyCross').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: What are the button html/css? I mean how you hide one button initially.

Comment: @AtanuCSE I just edit the question sorry. I just hide() one and show() the other. The Html is basic.

Comment: Add `:visible` to buttons, e.g. `$("#btnID:visible").on(`.

Comment: @Omar thanks, but I have the same problem with `$('#miniWeightLevel:visible').off('vclick').on('vclick'...` and 
`$('#minifyCross:visible').off('vclick').on('vclick'...`

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? I think it has to do with the time threshold on the click event. Take a look at this article: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/fast-touch-event-handling-eliminate-click-delay.html

Comment: How about using the attribute "disabled" in conjunction with your show/hide logic?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your code? I try to make it, but I can't reproduce your problem. Here is [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/02tf66xx/)

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this in the past as well, with `vclick` handlers firing twice on mobile devices. You can fix this by adding a `return false` at the end of your `vclick` handlers.

Check out these fiddles. This first one, http://jsfiddle.net/8g8mmzey/2/, is with your original code. Everything is fine when running on Chrome desktop. However, when running that on an iPhone, I can see that both events fire - when I click the 'x', the other button momentarily shows, but its click is then triggered, hiding it and showing the 'x' again.

The second fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ff23yL4u/ shows the updated code with `return false` at the end of the handlers.

```
$('#miniWeightLevel').unbind('vclick').bind('vclick', function (e) {        
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#miniWeightLevel').hide();
    $('#minifyCross').show();

    return false;
});
$('#minifyCross').unbind('vclick').bind('vclick', function (e) {       
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#miniWeightLevel').show();
    $('#minifyCross').hide();

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for e.preventDefault() worked is that stopPropagation is used to make sure the event doesn't bubble up the chain. eg. a click on a  tag would also fire click events on it's parent , and then its parent , etc. stopPropagation prevents this from happening.

preventDefault is used to stop the normal action of an element, eg. preventDefault in a click handler on a link would stop the link being followed, or on a submit button would stop the form being submitted.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I found the solution.

Instead of using `e.stopPropagation()` just use:

`e.preventDefault();`

Not sure why, but this solved my issue.

Comment: @down-voter: I don't really see why you down voted my answer. I found a solution that worked for me and I presented here. What's the problem with it?